# Function Derivable in a interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a function derivable in $I$ where $I$ is a arbitrary interval. If $f'(x)=0, \forall x \in I$ then $f$ is constant.

The known statement, or at least for me it is, is changing $I$ by $[a,b]$ and the conditions : $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and derivable in $(a,b)$.

Some idea to be able to start, I know that the medium-value theorem should be used, but I do not know how to fix the value.

Comment: Nitpick: “Differentiable”, not “derivable” — but I understand your meaning.

Comment: Thanks for correction :D

Answer (score 1):

Pick $x,y\in I$. Without loss of generality $x<y$. Then $[x,y]\subseteq I$ because $I$ is an interval. Now by the mean value theorem $f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)$ for some $\xi\in(x,y)$. But $f'(\xi)=0$, so $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks, is possible that f is derivable in $[a,b]$ ? for example ... $a$ is not  a left point of accumulation of ${a,b]$

Comment: Well, your assumption was that $f$ is differentiable (by the way, this is the correct word) in all $I$. But for the mean value theorem it is enough for $f$ to be only continuous in the corners and differentiable everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I know that by the initial data of the problem we can have that f is continuous in all I and the mean value theorem is valid. But my question goes by the fact if it is possible the fact that a function is differentiable in an interval . For example $[a, \infty)$ or $[a,b]$

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Look at my proof: I chose specific $x$ and $y$ and by working in the compact interval $[x,y]$ proved that $f(x)=f(y)$. So this way we get that $f$ is constant in all $I$, even if $I$ is a non-bounded interval.

Comment: Oh no, if I understand your test is perfect. But my question is whether there is any function f that is differentiable in an interval. It is generally said that f is continuous in [a, b] and differentiable in (a, b). My question was whether it can be differentiable in [a, b] I can not think of any concrete example, because the lateral derivatives would not exist at the extremes of the interval.

Comment: By definition, a function is differentiable in an interval $[a,b]$ if it is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and also the one sided derivatives exist in $a$ and $b$, which means the limits $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$ exist and are finite. So of course there are a lot of functions which are differentiable at $[a,b]$. Take any differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$ and restrict it to a compact interval, you will get it is differentiable there too.